# Capture filter value, within xslt, passed in from connected web part

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt, filter

Is it possible to get hold of the value of a filter being passed in by a connected web part?

For example, if a sharepoint list filter is sending a filter value of "1" to webpart A (a dataview webpart), I would like to re-use that value within the xslt of the dataview web part.

Thanks in advance.
KS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to access the Filter Value passed in by another web part.

Answer (score 0):

Perplexed,

Why are you taking the value as Filter... use "Get Parameters From" instead...

and then you can use the parameter anywhere, using @ParameterName

[Refer to this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010customization/thread/b053e934-51d5-4c96-a8f9-9d2cf47132db)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can use the parameter - was just curious as to whether or not the DataView web part exposed the filter being passed in. It would eliminate the need to create parameter definitions in two places and also then hooking the parameter to filter the rows.

Comment: hmm, I don't think there is a better solution than this... :)